# How to create an Url address for image in SQL Server Filetable

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, filetable, base64url

I have saved the image as base64 in the SQL Server FileTable.

Now I want to send the address of this file with API in string format for Android to be displayed with the Picasso library.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

FileTable files aren't natively accessible over http using a URI.  They are available over SMB using a UNC, eg `\\someserver\someshare\somefolder\somefile.jpg`

If you want to serve the images to an Android app, you'll need to add an HTTP endpoint to your back-end application to deliver file over http.

Comment: thank you .Finally, I made a URL from the image and posted the same link
And it was fixed